Help verifying answers on solving \$i\$ using superposition method
The problem in question

Need help on verifying answers.
 
For the first voltage source, I combined resistors that are in parallel with each other.
i = 12 V / (1.714 ohms + 1.875 ohms) = - 3.343 ohms (the result is negative because it's not flowing in the same direction as i)
For the second voltage source, I did the same as the previous one, but this time the result is positive because it's flowing in the same direction as i.
Are my answers so far correct?
Also, I'm confused on how should I do the current source one, what would you recommend as the best simplest method to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Hi, yes I've tried that and got lost on how to subtitute them. Would you mind helping?

are you trying to find a current? italicized I's refer to imaginary numbers.

Oh sorry, I didn't know that. Yes I'm trying to find current using superposition method.

Determine currents and voltages with the method of superposition of effects in the following circuit (The signs of the voltages and the directions of the currents refer to the first case):












